# How to use fastlane behind proxy

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-deliver, fastlane-pilot

I can't find any option about fastlane to set the proxy. So does there has a direct way to solve this?

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and for me [this site](https://github.com/infobyte/faraday/wiki/Proxy) helped as fastlane is using Faraday internally. You have to set up the proxy environment variables for faraday with the following commands:

```
$ export http_proxy="http://proxy_host:proxy_port"
$ export https_proxy="https://proxy_host:proxy_port"
```

Comment: Also you may need a proxy exclusion:


`$ export no_proxy="expamle.com"`

Comment: Wildcard using is `example.com`, not `*.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

Any of the Fastlane tools that use [spaceship](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship#readme) (i.e. the Apple APIs) can be proxied using a combination of three environment variables.

- `SPACESHIP_PROXY`: set the http proxy to use (`SPACESHIP_PROXY =https://localhost:9090`)
- `SPACESHIP_PROXY_SSL_VERIFY_NONE`: when present, disables SSL verification (to allow inspecting HTTPS requests)
- `SPACESHIP_DEBUG`: equivalent to `SPACESHIP_PROXY=https://127.0.0.1:8888 SPACESHIP_PROXY_SSL_VERIFY_NONE=1`, preconfigured for Charles Proxy defaults.

To use these, set them as environment variables in your shell, or prepend them to any fastlane command. For example, `SPACESHIP_PROXY=https://localhost:9090 bundle exec fastlane`

Source: [Spaceship debugging documentation](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/docs/Debugging.md#proxy-support)